# Android AlertDialog shows, but without any text

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, monodroid.dialog

I have a simple C# method to display an AlertDialog within my app. The dialog shows, but there is not text in it.

My code is this

```
    public static void Alert(Context context, string title, string message)
    {
        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.SetMessage(message);
        builder.SetTitle(title);
        builder.SetCancelable(false);
        builder.SetPositiveButton(Resource.String.Common_OK, (s, e) => builder.Dispose());
        var alert = builder.Create();
        alert.Show();
    }
```

title and string both contains text and the context is fine.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Xamarin.Android bug or something that has changed with ICS

Comment: I have a stupid question.  Are you sure you are in the UI thread?

Comment: Yes - it was the first thing I checked